# How do I make a recursive function stick to its for?

Tags: python, ethereum

I am making a recursive function for retrieving outer ethereum accounts. Once I loop through the first list of accounts, I want to take the first one and show the accounts he sent money to, then go back to previous interation take second account and so on.. problem is I don't know how to make my function stick to the for loop, because current account get replaced after the iteration..Any ideas

```
tx = get_transactions(start_address)


def breadth_search(transactions):
    if transactions:
        accounts = []
        for i, tran in enumerate(transactions):
            print(i, tran)
            if tran['tx_to'] not in accounts:
                accounts.append(tran['tx_to'])
        return accounts


def some_func(trans):
    tx_list = breadth_search(trans)
    for i, tr in enumerate(tx_list):
        print(i)
        breadth_search(get_transactions(tr))
    for i, tr in enumerate(tx_list):
        some_func(get_transactions(tr))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example and show what's your expected output?

Comment: @Ssein basically you start with an account that u pass to one of my other functions (get_transactions), that will retrieve all the accounts where the account 1 send his money. Then I need to to the same for account1.1, account 1.2 ... account 1.n and when these are finished, acccount 1.1 becomes account 2 and then retrieve accounts 2.1, 2.2 etc.

Comment: Like a depth-first pr breadth-first tree

Comment: Still it's not clear. Please edit your question and give an input sample and output which you wish to see. Please show, where you're using `tx`, what's , `trans`,`get_transactions()`....